# Is it possible to have a mutable type that is not garbage collected?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if such a thing can exist.  Can there be an object that is mutable but not  flagged as garbage collected ( specifically, tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC )

I have a C++ struct-like object that I'm writing and I'd like to know if all of its members are immutable.  I'm thinking of checking for the Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC flag to determine this.  If all members are immutable I want to speed up the deepcopy by doing a faster shallow copy, since I know members are immutable then it shouldn't have to go through an expensive deep copy.

Is this logically sound, or is there some mythical type that will blow me out of the water here.

Comment: Why would mutability have anything to do with the ability to garbage-collect something?

Comment: It certainly can exist, just don't opt into cycle GC. More sanely, consider a mutable type that doesn't contain any references, such as a hypothetical `MutableInt`. Also, `copy.deepcopy` [already doesn't copy](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/20225460ae0f/Lib/copy.py#l190) a number of immutable (and some mutable "atomic") types. Could you explain why that is not enough for you?

Comment: Robert: I figure GC is only needed for something that can lead to a cycle, and you cant create a cycle unless you are mutable.  Hence, if you are immutable you don't need GC.  The question is if you can be mutable but not flagged for GC

Comment: delnan: good point.  do you know of any existing types that might behave like this, not just hypotheticals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, any number of types created by extensions can not bother to implement GC, despite being mutable.

Secondly, a mutable type that doesn't contain other objects doesn't need to implement GC to avoid the creation of cycles. Thus you can't assume they will. For a specific example, see the `array.array` type.

Thirdly, just because an object is immutable doesn't mean it can't contain a mutable object. E.g., consider `([],)`.